# Send html email with python

Tags: html, email, python-3.x

I tried to send a email with html text using python.

The html text is loaded from a html file:

```
ft = open("a.html", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
text = ft.read()
ft.close()
```

And after, I send the email:

```
message = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: text/html\r\nSubject:
 %s\r\n\r\n%s" \
             % (sender,receiver,subject,text)
   try:
      smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
      smtpObj.starttls()
      smtpObj.login(username,password)
      smtpObj.sendmail(sender, [receiver], message)
      print("\nSuccessfully sent email")
   except SMTPException:
      print("\nError unable to send email")
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\email_prj\sendEmail.py", line 54, in <module>
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, [receiver] + ccn, message)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 745, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe0' in position 1554:
  ordinal not in range(128)

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\email_prj\sendEmail.py", line 56, in <module>
    except SMTPException:
  NameError: name 'SMTPException' is not defined
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> NameError: name 'SMTPException' is not defined

This is because in your current context, SMTPException doesn't stand for anything.

You'll need to do:

```
except smtplib.SMTPException:
```

---

Also, note that building the headers by hand is a bad idea. Can't you use inbuilt modules?

The below is a copy-paste of *relevant parts* from one of my projects.

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

....
....
....
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = self.username
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(self.username, self.password)
mailServer.sendmail(self.username, to, msg.as_string())
```